# How to search for a token by name on Cardano.io?

Tags: cardanoscan.io

Is there any way that I can get a token name on cardano explorer(cardano.io) like we can on other blockchains?  For example, Ethereum(etherscan.com) or Binance(bscscan.com)?

Why is it that almost all tokens on the Cardano Blockchain are not found in the CMC site?

I am looking for a token called "FLANO" but can't find it

Answer (score -1):

Try using this explorer to find tokens [(1)](https://cardanoassets.com/), it can find the `FLANO` token [(2)](https://cexplorer.io/asset/asset1f4k3qcrjrwm2w6z9ecxvgvsks6hx8s3umakf2x).